# Liferay theme won't enable?

Tags: java, css, portlet, liferay

I'm trying to enable a custom liferay theme.

The theme is located in `webapps/ROOT/html` (basically a copy of classic for now), and I've modified `liferay-look-and-feel.xml` as such:

```
<theme id="mytheme" name="mytheme">
    <root-path>/html/themes/cloudprint</root-path>
    <templates-path>${root-path}/templates</templates-path>
    <images-path>${root-path}/images</images-path>
    <template-extension>vm</template-extension>
    <roles>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </roles>
    <color-scheme id="01" name="Blue">
        <css-class>blue</css-class>
        <color-scheme-images-path>${images-path}/color_schemes/${css-class}</color-scheme-images-path>
    </color-scheme>
    <color-scheme id="02" name="Green">
        <css-class>green</css-class>
    </color-scheme>
    <color-scheme id="03" name="Orange">
        <css-class>orange</css-class>
    </color-scheme>
</theme>
```

In `ROOT/WEB-INF/classes`, I have `portal-ext.properties`:
`default.theme.id=mytheme`

I also tried `default.regular.theme.id` to no effect also. Everything still uses the `classic` theme.

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure a security role is set for the theme, or else it will not be set.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you already seem to have found something yourself: The officially supported way is to use the plugins sdk. With this you probably wouldn't have had this problem. Modifying the portal code itself is strongly discouraged (think about the maintenance effort for upgrading) and themes in ext-plugin (or the ext-environment for 5.2.x) are not supported.

That being said, you might be able to get them to work, but you make your life harder than necessary.